# Windows server 2008R2: Monitoring the amount of available entropy

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, entropy-pool

Is there any simple way of monitoring the amount of available entropy (random data) on windows?

I'm using Windows server 2008R2 and apache+ssl on vmware, and I'm a bit worried about starving the entropy pool.

On linux, this is available via /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has always enough entropy in PRNG.

Question is quality of this entropy.  [This document](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~dolev/pubs/thesis/msc-thesis-leo.pdf) and [this document](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xkrhovj/lectures/2008_PA168_WindowsRNG_slides.pdf) describe this topic very deeply.

To improve quality of entropy is good to consume it more often (as docs stays) to force re-keying.

Also look at MSDN for function [CryptGenRandom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)